# Ansible loop over list var

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to add users belongs to group `abc` into group `xyz`. to do this in ansible I am doing following

```
- name: Get the list of user belongs to abc group
  command: lid -g -n abc
  register: abc_users

- name: Add user belongs to abc group to xyz group
  user: name={{ items }} groups=xyz append=yes
  with_items: "{{ abc_users.stdout }}"
```

But getting following error

```
fatal: [10.8.17.14]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'items' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/#/workspace/#/ansible/roles/ubuntu-common/tasks/main.yml': line 26, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Add user belongs to sentience group to docker group\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Anyone know better way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `{{ items }}` with `{{ item }}`.

Update: as @udondan points out, iterate over `stdout_lines`

```
- name: Add user belongs to abc group to xyz group
  user: name={{ item }} groups=xyz append=yes
  with_items: "{{ abc_users.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: Also you want to loop over `abc_users.stdout_lines`, not `abc_users.stdout`. The latter is a string and you probably would loop over every char of that string. The first is a list, each line of the result being an element of that list.